# Predicted Probability with XGBClassifier ranging only from 0.48 to 0.51 for either class

Tags: logistic, classification, predictive-models, boosting, log-loss

**Why does my XGBClassifier predicts probability only from 0.48 to 0.51 for either class?**

I'm very new to `XGBoost`, so any suggestions are greatly appreciated! Here's what I want to do using `python`:

- I have a binary classification problem
- I want to get predicted probability for thresholding (so I want `predict_proba()`)
- Based on what I've read, `XGBClassifier` supports `predict_proba()`, so that's what I'm using

However, after I trained the model (hyperparameters at the end of the post), when I use `model.predict_proba(val_X)`, the output only ranges from `0.48` to `0.51` for either class. Something like this:

[image]

I've read a few other posts like ["xgboost logistic regression predictions are returning values >1 and < 0"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286995/xgboost-logistic-regression-predictions-are-returning-values-1-and-0), and ["How does gradient boosting calculate probability estimates?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350134/how-does-gradient-boosting-calculate-probability-estimates), but I can't figure out if the `predict_proba()` is giving me log odds or predicted probability, or what exactly is happening.

An answer to this post ["Unexpected probability distribution from xgboost binary classification"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/536188/unexpected-probability-distribution-from-xgboost-binary-classification) suggests that the model may not be learning anything from the data, and therefore the random probabilities. My `roc-auc` is `0.7662914691943129` and although I have class imbalance issue (`80%` of positive class), I've used the balanced class weights (`n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))`) during model training.

Here are the parameters for my model (I've used `optuna` to tune my hyperparameters):

```
 {'objective': 'binary:logistic',
 'use_label_encoder': False,
 'base_score': 0.5,
 'booster': 'gbtree',
 'colsample_bylevel': 1,
 'colsample_bynode': 1,
 'colsample_bytree': 1,
 'enable_categorical': False,
 'gamma': 0.20869504071834755,
 'gpu_id': -1,
 'importance_type': None,
 'interaction_constraints': '',
 'learning_rate': 9.48345478e-05,
 'max_delta_step': 0,
 'max_depth': 9,
 'min_child_weight': 1,
 'missing': nan,
 'monotone_constraints': '()',
 'n_estimators': 15,
 'n_jobs': 8,
 'num_parallel_tree': 1,
 'predictor': 'auto',
 'random_state': 0,
 'reg_alpha': 0.980300725,
 'reg_lambda': 0.00221248553,
 'scale_pos_weight': 0.24369747899159663,
 'subsample': 1,
 'tree_method': 'exact',
 'validate_parameters': 1,
 'verbosity': 0,
 'eval_metric': ['auc', 'logloss'],
 'lambda': 0.002212485584996869,
 'alpha': 0.980300751529644,
 'eta': 9.483455063850674e-05,
 'grow_policy': 'depthwise'}
```

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Did your model perhaps fit only a small number of trees? A constant (or close to constant) prediction is correct -- it's the optimal thing to do -- in problems where X is not very predictive of Y. If you don't have much signal, your predictions will be close to constant.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! I think that's what's happening! I may have too much regularization and it prevented the model from learning the signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Adrian already pointed out, the reason the predicted probabilities are close to 0.5 is because the model has very small number of trees

```
'n_estimators': 15
```

and at the same time a small learning rate

```
'learning_rate': 9.48345478e-05
```

which cannot produce predictions that deviate much from the initial prediction of 0.5 by default.

One further comment is that these results from hyperparameter search is likely due to using `roc-auc` as (stopping) criteria. These predicted probabilities may be sufficient to produce optimal rank ordering metrics, but not necessarily producing probability close to expected values.